# Changing position of submenu with jQuery when it slips out of the screen

Tags: jquery, css

I create a 3-level dropdown menu in CSS3 where the submenus drop down vertically. Everything is fine, the only problem is when the menu (`.main-menu > li` -> see the code below) is too close to the right-hand side of the screen, some part of its submenu disappears as it 'slips out' of the screen and it becomes invisible.

I want to improve the menu with some jQuery by changing the floating direction of the current submenu if it's too close to the side of the screen. As I'm a novice in jQuery, could you help me a little?

The main structure of the HTML is:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu Point 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Point 1.1</a>
          <ul> 
            <li><a href="#">Menu Point 1.1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Point 1.1.2</a></li>
            ....
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Point 1.2</a></li>
        ....
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Point 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Point 2.1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Point 2.1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Point 2.1.2</a></li>
            ....
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Point 2.2</a></li>
        ....
      </ul>
    </li>
    .....
  </ul>
</nav>
```

As far as I can see the jQuery should do these things:

1. Measure the width of 1st-level submenu + 2nd-level submenu (x)
2. Measure the distance between the left-hand side position of `.main-menu > li` and the right-hand side position of the screen (y)
3. `if (y-x)<0 { 
       float the submenus to the left (by default they float to the right);
      }`

Do you have any suggestions how should I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I came to the solution by myself, here is the code if someone is interested:

```
$(".main-menu > li > ul > li").addClass("submenu-1");
$(".main-menu > li > ul > li > ul > li").addClass("submenu-2");

$(".main-menu > li").on("mouseover", function() {

    if($(this).find(".submenu-1").length > 0 ) {
      var clientWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
      var menuDist1 = $(this).find(".submenu-1").offset().left;
      var menuWidth = $(this).width();
      var menuWidth1 = $(this).find(".submenu-1").width();
      var menuWidth2 = $(this).find(".submenu-2").width();

      var menuPosition = menuDist1 + menuWidth1 + menuWidth2;

      if (menuPosition > clientWidth) {
        var newPosition1 = menuWidth - menuWidth1;
        var newPosition2 = -menuWidth1;

        $(this).find(".submenu-1").parent("ul").css("left", newPosition1);
        $(this).find(".submenu-2").parent("ul").css("left", newPosition2);
      }
   }    
});
```